# Rails- How can I use simple ruby classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some simple ruby classes that I want to use with rails (they are classes for things like points, lines, rectangles, etc.).  How can I use them with a rails controller or an active record model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The convention is to put them in `your-app/lib/`. You can have Rails automatically load them by configuring it to do so in `config/application.rb`. Edit the default to look something like this:

```
# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
config.autoload_paths += %W( #{Rails.root}/lib/shapes )
```

Where your class definition files are in `your-app/lib/shapes`.

***Note**: This is for Rails 3. Rails 2.x automatically loads files from lib.*